# Как определить куда идет запрос?

Tags: веб-сервер, mod-rewrite

Не знаю, возможно ли это. Делаю клиент для сайта. В html выведены я вижу ссылку, например `site.ru/user/id/5`, а реальная ссылка такая: `site.ru/user/index.php?id=5` (наобум узнал). Как можно узнать куда в конце концов приходит запрос? Получится ли это сделать в Chrome?

Comment: @Flippy, поясните, что вы имеете в виду под "в html выведены", это на веб-странице в браузере или в коде страницы?

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, в html коде. Причем там есть "грязные ссылки" непонятной архитектуры типа `chat/wi:int:=107:form:msg:IFL:;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от того, на чем сайт написан. Перенаправление может быть на клиентском уровне (в html или ajax), тогда его возможно отследить, а если перенаправление настроено на серверном уровне (java servlet например), тогда вы никогда не узнаете, куда сервер ваши запросы отправляет, вы сможете увидеть только адрес входа, куда *ВЫ* их отправляете, и ответ сервера в виде html, json, или еще чего-то. А что происходит внутри сервера - остается внутри сервера.

Answer (score 0):

В Chrome есть DevTools, который открывается через f12, далее открыть вкладку Network, в ней выбрать раздел xhr или all, далее нажать на вашу ссылку, чтобы прошел запрос, он сразу же должен отобразиться в списке. Выделите его и в появившемся описании выбрать раздел headers. В нем в списке General найти пункт "Request URL"
[image: Примерно так это выглядит]